# Track device network activity

Tags: networking, tracking

Context can be added to this question if needed - let me know in a comment.

I need to log the network activity of my Nintendo DSi. I tried WireShark and Microsoft Network Monitor but couldn't get either to find the info I wanted. The best I got was finding that "NintendoDS" had connected to the network, but I couldn't see any of the HTTP traffic it was generating.

As for manual solutions, I successfully redirected one of the domains I knew the DS was accessing to an HTTP listener I made in PHP, received the HTTP request, and sent a 404 response (thus generating an error on the DS's software and cleanly ending the connection).

Does anyone have any recommendations for how to track such network activity? All I really need to find out is what domains the DS is connecting to, so I can use the router's DNS to redirect them.

Comment: Can you configure a proxy for the DSi? Can you establish a wireless connection directly to your computer (i.e. have it appear as infrastructure, or an ad-hoc network)?

Comment: I can create an ad-hoc network on the computer, however the last time I tried that the DS was unable to connect to it (it would connect, then lose the connection a second later, re-establish, then lose it again, then give up)

Comment: How do you have wireshark setup? Here is a guide to various different methods of capturing using wireshark: http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Ethernet. Here is a bunch of tools and scripts you may find useful: http://wiki.wireshark.org/Tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an old Ethernet hub (not an Ethernet switch) I keep for this purpose.

[image: Netgear EN104 hub]
[image: Hubbing out]

You could instead buy or [hack](http://hackaday.com/2008/09/14/passive-networking-tap/) a [network tap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_tap)

[image: Ethernet Tap]

There's an [excellent article](http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Ethernet) at the Wireshark Wiki which covers these and more (switch + monitoring port, man-in-the-middle …).

Answer (score 0):

wireshark should eb able to do this, so perhaps you need to look at the physical arrangement of the network and place the wireshark listener further upstream.

personally, i'd use ntop for this.