# How can I route internet traffic via another computer to sniff the connection?

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, nat

I need to do port forwarding on Windows 7.

I have machine `A` that runs a program, which connects to the internet. I need to debug this connection, and I can't install a sniffer for checking the packet transmission on this machine.

I want to connect `A` to another  machine `B`. I would install a sniffer there, and use machine `B` to forward the packets to the internet.

This is why I need to install/enable a NAT server on `B`, which uses Windows 7.

Comment: Port forwarding is usually done at a router between your computer and your Internet service provider. Can you describe your Internet connection setup, or at least explain why you need port forwarding?

Comment: I have program that need connect to WAN but it failed then I want check the packet transmit by sniffer I can't install sniffer on local machine my switch I havn't prmit run there sniffer

Comment: If you can't install anything on machine A and you can on Machine B, there are options without any port forwarding. Here are some setups to capture traffic using wireshark: http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Ethernet

Comment: you might find more help at: http://serverfault.com/

Comment: @Conrad.Dean It would be better not to ask these kinds of questions on Server Fault. It'd be off-topic there … or at least there's no reason to ask elsewhere when he can get help here as well.

Comment: This is similar to http://superuser.com/questions/342490/track-device-network-activity/342543#342543

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to use  [`tcpbridge`](http://tcpreplay.synfin.net/wiki/tcpbridge).

I send the data from `A` to `B`, and on `B` I run the sniffer.

Then, I send the packets to the real destnation by using `tcpbridge`.